# C# Exclude Parameters From File Paths

Tags: c#, file, parameters, path

I'm reading startup items from registry and checking if associated files exist.

Example registry values:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\amd64\CLIStart.exe" MSRun

C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\amd64\CLIStart.exe MSRun

"C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\amd64\CLIStart.exe" /parameter

"C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\amd64\CLIStart.exe" -paramaeter1 -parameter2

C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\amd64\CLIStart.exe -MSRun /parameter

"C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\amd64\CLIStart.exe -MSRun /parameter"
```

How can i exclude the parameters? I only want `C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\amd64\CLIStart.exe` part.

How operating system makes this separation?

Comment: I don't think there is a built in method to do that. What I would do is to first get rid of the quotation marks, then `Path.GetExtension`, remove everything after (and including) the first space in the extension and then `Path.Combine` it back together again.

Comment: @Corak it fails when the registry value is like "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPcap\rpcapd.exe" -d -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPcap\rpcapd.ini"

Comment: Okay, try getting rid of quotations again and then `string.Split` it by spaces. Then try if the first one `File.Exists`, then `+= " " + second` and so on, until `File.Exists` returns true. - Or if it starts with a quotation mark, find the next one and take what's between.

Answer (score 0):

Is this by any chance a homework exercise?
Anyway, this would achieve the wanted result.

```
return yourPath.Trim('\"').Substring(0, yourPath.LastIndexOf(".exe") + 3);
```

Comment: But file extension can vary, it's not always an executable file. And it will fail when registry value is like "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPcap\rpcapd.txt" -d -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPcap\rpcapd.ini"

Comment: " I only want C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\amd64\CLIStart.exe part." I assumed you would only want the executables judging by that. I'll try to think of something (a bit busy at the moment, might take a while) and will update the answer at some point later.